# How to create element pairs of two lists by iterating through them in parallel?

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, python-3.x

I want to iterate through two lists in parallel and create element pairs as follows.

**My code:**

```
q_node_roots = ['A', 'B', 'C']
s_node_roots = ['X', 'Y', 'Z']

for q_node_pair, s_node_pair in zip([q_node_roots, q_node_roots[1:]], 
                                    [s_node_roots, s_node_roots[1:]]):
    print q_node_pair, s_node_pair
```

**Expected Output:**

```
['A', 'B'] ['X', 'Y']
['B', 'C'] ['Y', 'Z']
```

**Generated Output:**

```
['A', 'B', 'C'] ['X', 'Y', 'Z']
['B', 'C'] ['Y', 'Z']
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> lis1 = ['A', 'B', 'C']
>>> lis2 = ['X', 'Y', 'Z']
>>> z1 = zip(lis1,lis1[1:])  #use itertools.izip in py2x for memory efficiency
>>> z2 = zip(lis2,lis2[1:])
>>> for x,y in zip(z1,z2):
...     print x,y

('A', 'B') ('X', 'Y')
('B', 'C') ('Y', 'Z')
```

Comment: Any way to achieve the same using 'for loop', since a lot of computation is performed based on each pair of pairs generated.

Comment: @ArunprasathShankar I've used a for-loop, by the way you can use `itertools.izip` in py2x to get an iterator.